# How to run cleanup with vows.js?

Tags: node.js, bdd, vows

I'm using Vows.js to test some node.js which is creating records in a database. As a result of this it creates some test records in the database. I'd like to remove these records once the tests have run. Is there a way to run a cleanup function when  a batch of tests is run in Vows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define the `teardown` function in your context that is executed once all the tests in your context are run.

```
vows.describe('Foo').addBatch({
    'A Context' : {
       topic : { foo: 'bar' },
       'it works' : function (topic) { assert.equal(topic.foo, "bar"); },
       teardown : function (topic) { topic.foo = "baz" }
    }
});
```

You can see this in [Vows own tests](https://github.com/cloudhead/vows/blob/master/test/vows-test.js).

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would use a separate test database when running automated tests, and empty that database before each test run.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open pull request for vows implementing afterSuite:

https://github.com/phstc/vows/commit/d5b40e85e924e06cca560b4d8d6a264528bbab2b